# Checking for parity errors with pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm currently writing a small utility in python to monitor the communications on a serial line. This is being used to debug some hardware that is connected via rs232 so being able to see *exactly* what's going over the line is extremely important. How do I check for parity errors using pyserial?

Specifically I'm wondering if there is a platform independent way of finding the value of the parity bit using pyserial. I'd strongly prefer to not need `termios` to do this as this is used on some windows machines.

Comment: How would you define a "parity error"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DanLenski, specifically I want to see what the value of the parity bit in the serial frames are.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your hardware setup looks like, but I believe that in standard PC serial ports the parity checking occurs at the hardware level so it's not going to be visible to the software. If you wish to implement a "[bit-banging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging)" serial port which would let you inspect the individual bits on the line, then you'll probably have to use different hardware... making some kind of GPIO interface?

Comment: I could set up a microcontroller to receive the serial then send that over to the computer along with the parity bits and any frame error information by sending 2 bytes for every byte received. That output would then be parsed by the script. However that's exactly the effort I wanted to avoid by just using a couple of usb-to-serial convertors along with pyserial. I guess if it's not possible I'll look into the microcontroller based approach again.

Comment: I found a couple other threads that might help you out. These discuss various intricacies of reading raw data from serial ports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437593, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606291

Answer (score 0):

I monitored the parity bit by bit banging with the GPIO4 on my Pi.

Inspiration [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44276/reading-weird-serial-communication-gpio/44294#44294)

My solution is outputting the parity bit in a second byte and writing all into a file:

```
import time
import pigpio # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

RXD=4 # number of GPIO pin

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    exit(0)

pigpio.exceptions = False # Ignore error if already set as bit bang read.

handle = pi.file_open("/home/pi/Documents/bit_bang_output.txt",pigpio.FILE_WRITE) #assuming that the file /opt/pigpio/access (yes without extension) contains a line /home/pi/Domcuments/* w

pi.bb_serial_read_open(RXD, 9600,9) # Set baud rate and number of data bits here. Reading 9 data bits will read the parity bit.

pigpio.exceptions = True

stop = time.time() + 5.0 # recording 5.0 seconds

while time.time() < stop:

    (count, data) = pi.bb_serial_read(RXD)
    if count:
        #print(data.hex(),end="")
        pi.file_write(handle, data.hex())

pi.bb_serial_read_close(RXD)

pi.stop()
```